# Systemd boot time trimming

Tags: systemd

I just switched to systemd on debian sid and while it's a big step forward it also makes it easy to see opportunities for improvement

**Boot from suspend** takes too long

```
$ systemd-analyze blame | head -4
         13.807s systemd-suspend.service
          2.167s mysql.service
          1.497s apache2.service
           163ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-f9ce6b25\x2d061b\x2d453e\x2db1f7\x2d0f560cd3181c.service
```

As you can see, `systemd-suspend.service` takes ages. Standard boot is  very quick but from suspend it's slower than sysvinit! Where should I be looking?

**Mysql blocking** a faster boot

```
$ systemd-analyze critical-chain | head -7
The time after the unit is active or started is printed after the "@" character.
The time the unit takes to start is printed after the "+" character.

graphical.target @2.839s
└─multi-user.target @2.839s
  └─exim4.service @2.773s +66ms
    └─mysql.service @604ms +2.167s
```

A whopping 76% of my `graphical.target` is spent waiting for mysql. Is there any way to stop it blocking?

**Edit:** nkts made me realise these are all running in sysvinit compat mode - I bet that's what's holding this up. How do I install systemd startup files on debian?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to look at exim4.service and see if there's a dependency on multi-user.target. IMHO graphical interface and mail service are unrelated.

Comment: An excelent point that leads me to realise that `mysql.service`, `apache2.service` and `exim4.service` are being run in sysvinit compat mode from `/etc/init.d` - know any way to convert them to systemd or manually remove the bottleneck? Where is the systemd file for init.d running?